# Why do undefined constants evaluate to true?

Tags: php, constants

Stupid question - I'm surprised this one has bitten me.  Why do undefined constants in PHP evaluate to true?

Test case:

```
<?php
    if(WHATEVER_THIS_ISNT_DEFINED)
        echo 'Huh?';
?>
```

The above example prints 'Huh?'

Thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: Wow, PHP surprises again. Probable reason: "because it doesn't evaluate to false" :)

Comment: Nope, no surprises.  The warning explains everything, "Notice:  Use of undefined constant MY_CONST - assumed 'MY_CONST' in some_script.php on line 5".  Develop with notices and warnings turned on!  :)

Comment: Keep  the [PHP loose comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) in mind for why `"WHATEVER_THIS_ISNT_DEFINED" == TRUE`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `defined('WHATEVER_THIS_ISNT_DEFINED')`

When PHP encounters a constant that is not defined, it throws an `E_NOTICE`, and uses the constant name you've tried to use as a string. That's why your snippet prints `Huh!`, because a non-empty string (which is not `"0"`) will evaluate to `true`.

From the manual:

> If you use an undefined constant, PHP
>   assumes that you mean the name of the
>   constant itself, just as if you called
>   it as a string (CONSTANT vs
>   "CONSTANT"). An error of level
>   E_NOTICE will be issued when this
>   happens.

If you set your error reporting level to report `E_NOTICE`s, which is a good practice during development, you will also see the notice thrown.

- [PHP Constant Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)
- [defined()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php)
- [Casting to Boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)
- [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)
- [error_reporting() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: You actually need `defined('WHATEVER_THIS_ISNT_DEFINED')`.  Without the quotes, it triggers the exact same notice error.

Comment: @Frank Thanks, I was too busy on improving the other parts of my answer :).

Answer (score 7):

From the manual:

> If you use an undefined constant, PHP assumes that you mean the name of the constant itself, just as if you called it as a string (CONSTANT vs "CONSTANT").

Basically, if `WHATEVER_THIS_ISNT_DEFINED` isn't defined, PHP interprets it as `"WHATEVER_THIS_ISNT_DEFINED"`.  Non-empty strings evaluate to `true`, so your expression will always pass (unless `WHATEVER_THIS_ISNT_DEFINED` *is* defined and set to a falsey value.)

This is, frankly, stupid behaviour. It was implemented, I believe, to allow things like `$foo[bar]` to work when the programmer should have used `$foo['bar']`. It's illogical behaviour like this that makes people think PHP isn't a real programming language.

The way to test whether a constant is defined is with [`defined`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php).

Answer (score 2):

Undefined constants are treated as strings by PHP: [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).  Taking that fact, think it through in English language:

```
If "WHATEVER_THIS_ISNT_DEFINED", then do something.
```

... it is logical that it is "true" - you aren't comparing anything to anything else.

That is why, when doing `if` statements, it is best practice to include a specific evaluation.  If you're checking for false, put it in the code: `if (something === false)` vs `if (something)`.  If you're checking to see if it is set, use `isset`, and so on.

Also, this highlights the importance of developing with notices and warnings enabled.  Your server will throw a notice for this issue:

> Notice:  Use of undefined constant
>   MY_CONST - assumed 'MY_CONST' in
>   some_script.php on line 5

Turn on notices and warnings to develop, turn them off for production.  Can only help!

Answer (score 2):

Try [`defined()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php). If it's not defined then the constant assumes it's simply text.

Answer (score 1):

Note that constant name must always be quoted when defined.

e.g.

- `define('MY_CONST','blah')` - *correct*
- `define(MY_CONST,'blah')` - *incorrect*

also

```
<?php
 if (DEBUG) {
    // echo some sensitive data.
 }
 ?>
 and saw this warning:
 "Use of undefined constant DEBUG - assumed 'DEBUG'"

A clearer workaround is to use
 <?php
 if (defined('DEBUG')) {
    // echo some sensitive data.
 }
 ?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

It's not just constants, it is a much **broader** issue with PHP's parsing engine. (You ought to see warnings in your logs.)

In PHP, "bare words" that it doesn't recognize are generally treated as strings that happen to be missing their quotes, and strings with a non-zero length [tend to evaluate to true](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Try this:

```
$x =  thisisatest ;
$y = "thisisatest";
if($x == $y){
    echo("They are the same");
}
```

You should see "They are the same".

Comment: It is not a broader issue, it only applies to constants (which are basically bare words). In your example `thisisatest` is an undefined constant. It is only a naming convention to use uppercase letters for constants.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in addition to `defined()` you can also use strict type checking using `===`

```
<?php
if(WHATEVER_THIS_ISNT_DEFINED === true) // Or whatever type/value you are trying to check
    echo 'Huh?';
```