Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value:
This is an error after changing to php8.3 and MariaDB 11.3.
Where did I go wrong?
Please take a look.
echo "$_SESSION[Iyagi_Id]','$today','$img','$title','$weath','$mood1','$mood2','$happy','$love','$c[web_edit]','$text";
The input values are as follows.
1111','2024-5-15','','This is the title.','','','','','','','This is the content.
Maria DB (11.3) Query (line 72)
mysqli_query($connect , "insert into hani_diary (id,day,img,title,weath,mood1,mood2,happy,love,html,text) values('$_SESSION[Iyagi_Id]','$today','$img','$title','$weath','$mood1','$mood2','$happy','$love','$c[web_edit]','".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $text)."')") or die("입력 에러");
js_move("./memo_write.php?year=$year&month=$month&day=$day");

Error message
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value: '' for column gagebu.hani_diary.happy at row 1 in /home/gagebu/www/memo/memo_write.php:72 Stack trace: #0 /home/gagebu/www/memo/memo_write.php(72): mysqli_query() #1 {main} thrown in /home/gagebu/www/memo/memo_write.php on line 72
I am trying to insert data into Maria DB.

The message, and the values in your variables suggest that a value of '' is not acceptable for a field that expects an integer. Change it to whatever value represents the default.

Does this answer your question? How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?

$c[web_edit] - can you explain what this variable should be resolved to? Do you use any constant called web_edit in your code?

More probably, this $c[web_edit] is a case of undefined constant (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6207037/24943937), actually evaluated as $c["web_edit"]. Same for $_SESSION[Iyagi_Id], evaluated as $_SESSION["Iyagi_Id"].

You are inserting a record, and trying to set the field happy to a value of an empty string, or "".
But in your Maria DB table hani_diary, the field happy is configured to be an integer.
Either change the configuration of your table to something capable of holding text (for example, text), or make sure your variable $happy holds an integer.
